# Adding column with datetime datatype using alter table statement but with a different value in each row

Tags: mysql

I have a relation named Tweets with some columns. Now, I want to add a column named Timestamp with data type DATETIME but the problem is if I set a default value using now() all the rows get the same value. I want every row to have a different value. I cannot use rand() function along with now() as Mysql shall throw an error. So, how can I achieve this? Requesting assistance.

table creation code:

```
create table Tweets(
tweet_id int primary key,
tweet_data varchar(160) not null,
posted_by int not null,
type int not null,
belongs_to_nest int,
constraint posted_by_foreign_key foreign key(posted_by) references Users(user_id),
constraint type_foreign_key foreign key(type) references Types(type_id),
constraint belongs_to_nest_foreign_key foreign key(belongs_to_nest) references Nests(nest_id)
);
```

I am using this query as of now:

```
alter table Tweets add column Timestamp datetime not null unique default (now());
```

How should I modify this query so as to get a unique value in each row. From unique I mean is seconds must be different in each row although date, hours and minutes may be same.

Comment: You want *different value* but what value?

Comment: different datetime value....basically the seconds must be unique in all the rows.

Comment: *"You want different value but what value?"* isn't it clear? @forpas he wants to have a different  value for that value ...  Topicstarter see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as this question is unclear and will be most likely voteclosed.

Comment: *"Timestamp with data type DATETIME"* i would suggest using `DATETIME(6)` and let MySQL use `DEFUALT CURRENT_TIME(6)`

Comment: 13:47:01 alter table Tweets add column Timestamp datetime(6) not null unique default (current_timestamp(6)) Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '2019-06-14 13:47:01.567964' for key 'Timestamp' 1.062 sec      
I get this error. @RaymondNijland

Comment: Start by sharing the `SHOW CREATE TABLE Tweets` ..

Comment: i assume the tweet_id is a auto_increment column?

Comment: no its not.@RaymondNijland

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this.

First you should add that datetime field without making it unique since there's no data in it yet OR you could add it unique and allow null until you've successfully filled all the dates.

Once this is done, populate the date (maybe do something like:

```sql
alter table Tweets add column Timestamp datetime not null default (now());
```

```sql
UPDATE Tweets SET Timestamp = NOW() + date_add(date, INTERVAL tweet_id DAY);
```

Then once this is done you can add a unique key to your table

```sql
ALTER TABLE Tweets add unique key unique timestamp_idx (Timestamp);
```

And call it a day.

That being said, I feel really dirty providing you with such solution because I have no idea how creating random dates to existing tweets would be useful, but hey who am I to judge.